# How to infer keyof array's content in function call based on provided object

Tags: typescript

I would like to have Typescript predicting the type of my second argument in function `doSomethingWithMyArray` based on my input object provided on my first argument.

Example:

```
interface IPerson {
    name: string;
}
let myArr: IPerson[];


// should present a error 
doSomethingWithMyArray(myArr, 'key_of_element_in_array') 

// should be accepted
doSomethingWithMyArray(myArr, 'name')
```

I tried this but clearly, keyof<T[]> doesn't work:

```
interface IPerson { name: string; }
const a: IPerson = {name: 'A'};
const b: IPerson = {name: 'B'};
const d: IPerson[] = [a,b];
type f = typeof a[];

function doSomethingWithMyArray<T>(arg1: T, arg2: keyof<T[]> ) {
  // do something....
}
// should predict 'name'
doSomethingWithMyArray(d, '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the keys of `T` by using `keyof T[number]`:

```
function doSomethingWithMyArray<
  T extends any[]
>(arg1: T, arg2: keyof T[number] ) { }
```

You also have to constrain `T` to be an array with `T extends any[]`. Otherwise TypeScript will not allow the `T[number]` notation as `T` could be anything.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVoGcD2JkDeyIcAthAFzJZhSgDmA3MgL4BQCeNycVG2eZAF5CJclQDkAQQktGHLmGQAjPpii58IgmMrIJAIVnzOIbgBM1AkAG0AusOQ24AGmV35YAJ4AHFDEdvPxwAuHt5NhgAVxAEMGBBcxwAZRxyMAALBgB1YEyAWS8pKCg4LwAeABVkCAAPSBBzLB4QL3sAPgAKOCh6AEYqSpceXoAmKgBrCC8Q5EqbECjSZWgHAEpCNmRkNnY2JNT0rJB6XIKikrLO82GJCTX5A7SITJy8jMLi0q9r2917xhAA)